# Android: Fragment but can't see an ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, android-actionbar, fragment

Long time listener, first time poster. I'm a newbie to Android but have been working my way through the Big Ranch Guide examples in an effort to improve my understanding.

I am trying to display an action bar in the following class.

```
public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
    private Crime mCrime;
    private EditText mTitleField; 
    private Button mDateButton;
    private Button mTimeButton; 
    private CheckBox mSolvedCheckedBox;
    public static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID =    "com.example.criminalIntent";
   private static final String DIALOG_DATE = "date";
   private static final String DIALOG_TIME = "time";
   private static final int REQUEST_DATE = 0;
   private static final int REQUEST_TIME = 1;

@TargetApi(11)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UUID crimeId = (UUID)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
    mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

public void updateDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat datFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat timFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss zzz");
    mDateButton.setText(datFormat.format(mCrime.getDate()));
    mTimeButton.setText(timFormat.format(mCrime.getDate()));

}

@TargetApi(11)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, parent, false);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

        if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {

            if (getActivity().getActionBar() == null){
                Log.d("CrimeFragment", "Sh*t!!");
            } else

            getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            //((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }


    mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
    mTitleField.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
    mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence c, int start, int before, int count){
            mCrime.setTitle(c.toString());
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence c, int start, int before, int count){
            //leave blank
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable c) {
            //leave blank
        }
    });


    mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date); 
    mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(mCrime.getDate());
            dialog.setTargetFragment(CrimeFragment.this, REQUEST_DATE);
            dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_DATE);

        }
    });

    mTimeButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_time); 
    mTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            TimePickerFragment dialog = TimePickerFragment.newInstance(mCrime.getDate());
            dialog.setTargetFragment(CrimeFragment.this, REQUEST_TIME);
            dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_TIME);

        }
    });

    mSolvedCheckedBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
    mSolvedCheckedBox.setChecked(mCrime.getSolved());
    mSolvedCheckedBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
            mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
        }
    });
    updateDate();
    return v;
}

//This adds a crime unique identifier to the fragment for retrieval by CrimeActivity
public static CrimeFragment newInstance(UUID crimeId) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID, crimeId);

    CrimeFragment fragment = new CrimeFragment(); 
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        //to be implemented next

        if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity())!= null){
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
        }   
            return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(("MM/DD/yyyy"));
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK){
        return;
    } 
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATE) {
        Date date = (Date)data.getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
        mCrime.setDate(date);
        updateDate();
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TIME) {
        Date date = (Date)data.getSerializableExtra(TimePickerFragment.EXTRA_TIME);
        mCrime.setDate(date);
        updateDate();
    }
}
```

}

StackOverflow has been an incredible help in offering a number of solutions to his problem. I have tried the following.

1. Extending by ActionBarActivity : creates Havoc with the onCreate.
2. Update the Manifest file to include a theme with an actionbar; did this @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
3. Try casting the ActionBar to (ActionBarActivity): didn't work
4. Try the getSupportActionBar(): didn't work
5. Try item name="android:windowActionBar" = true in the styles.xml; i've tried this.

As you can see from the code I'm targeting the view function at API11 also. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thank you for commenting, it is invoked from a menu in CrimeListActivity as follows.

```
public class CrimeListFragment extends ListFragment {
private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;
private static final String TAG = "CrimeListFragment";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            //getActivity().getActionBar().show();
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.crimes_title); 
    mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();


    CrimeAdapter adapter = new CrimeAdapter(mCrimes);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    Crime c = (Crime)(getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
    Log.d(TAG, c.getTitle() + " was clicked");

    //Start CriminalPagerActivity
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CrimePagerActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(CrimeFragment.EXTRA_CRIME_ID, c.getId());
    startActivity(i); 
}

private class CrimeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Crime> {

    public CrimeAdapter(ArrayList<Crime> crimes){
        super(getActivity(), 0, crimes);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // if no view, inflate one. 
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, null);
        }

        //Configure the view for this Crime
        Crime c = mCrimes.get(position); 

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_titleTextView);
        titleTextView.setText(c.getTitle());
        TextView dateTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_dateTextView);
        dateTextView.setText(c.getDate().toString());
        CheckBox solvedCheckBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox);
        solvedCheckBox.setChecked(c.getSolved());

        return convertView;
        }
    }

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((CrimeAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_crime_list, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_new_crime:
        Crime crime = new Crime(); 
        CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).addCrime(crime);
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CrimePagerActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(CrimeFragment.EXTRA_CRIME_ID, crime.getId());
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Where's the activity that contains this fragment?

Comment: The fragment has nothing to do with the ActionBar. What's your minSdk? Also what theme are you using (in styles.xml)?

Comment: ok, ok I got it. Extending the pagerViewer above by ActionBarActivity did it. What did I learn? The host Activity sets the page preferences for the Fragment. Thanks for listening.